# Calculus notation question from old theoretical biology paper

Tags: calculus, notation

I'm working through *The Moulding of Senescence by Natural Selection* from 1966, and it uses an odd notation, $(\delta_x)(q_x)/(\delta x)$. I haven't seen the notation in the numerator. I'm assuming it's not equivalent to dq_x/dx, but it's not explained in the paper and I'm not sure how I'd even Google it to figure out what it means. Can anyone explain? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Could you please add some more context, it is hard to discern what it is supposed to mean the with just this expression.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it looks like something from the calculus of variations, but like it was already said, this doesn't look like anything standard, and you're probably going to have to provide more context to get any reasonable answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked at the paper and it seems that the notation used is the same as that of [actuarial notation for life tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation#Life_tables).

In particular,

$${}_{\;\;\;\delta x}q_x = \text{ the probability of death between ages } x \text{ and } x+\delta x \; .$$

So, the $\delta x$ is not indicating a derivative, but is a front index of the mortality variable $q$ and it indicates the time interval over which a death might occur.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta q$ in mechanics at least refers to a variation.

A variation is a change that does not occur in time.

For example, suppose you have a system of particles with positions and momenta $q_i, p_i$ subject to a central force.

And you'd like to see the effect a small instantaneous change in one of the particles positions on the system dynamics.

$\delta q_i$ refers to a variation in particle's  $i$ position.

This variation is not dependent on time.

from this you can derive Lagrangian mechanics.

In a continuous system (take a string for example) the discrete index $i$ is replaced with $x\in R$.

so the variation $\delta q_x$ allows you to derive the forces acting on the string and develop the wave equation as a limiting process of discrete variations.